# I am getting "Must declare variable" when running my C# code to query a SQL DB

Tags: c#, sql

I currently have a webconfig that had the following key and value `<add key="AuthRoles" value="test1;test2;test3;test4" />`.  I currently have the following code.  I am getting the following error when running it`Must declare the scalar variable "@roleId".`

**CODE**

```
  public bool IsUserAuthorized(string UserID)
    {
        bool isAuthed = false;
        try
        {
            string _constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionDD"].ConnectionString;

            string authorizedGroup = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthRoles"].ToString();

            string[] authGroup = authorizedGroup.Split(';');

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_constring))
            {
                try
                {
                    StringBuilder cmdTxt = new StringBuilder();
                    cmdTxt.Append("SELECT EmployeeID, RoleID, RoleDescription");
                    cmdTxt.Append(" FROM vstaffInfo");
                    cmdTxt.Append(" WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeId AND RoleId = @roleId");
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdTxt.ToString(), con);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", UserID);

                    for (int x = 0; x < authGroup.Length; x++)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roleIdr", authGroup[x]);

                        if (authGroup.Length != x - 1)
                        {
                            cmdTxt.Append(" OR RoleId = ");
                        }
                    }

                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    rdr.Close();
                    con.Close();
                }
```

**The SQL statement will look like this**

```
SELECT EmployeeID, RoleID, RoleDescription
FROM vEmployeeRoleInfo
WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeId
AND RoleId = test1
Or RoleId = test2
Or RoleId = test3
Or RoleId = test4
```

**Error**

`Must declare the scalar variable "@roleId".`

Comment: How about the `IN` statement instead?

Comment: @Adam you can't really use `IN` with parameters.

Comment: @CodeCaster - good point.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Awesome I been looking at this code for over 2 hours and could not find that, wrote the title due to frustration, corrected the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. first of all you are using cmdTxt to produce a command before you have made all the appending you need. There is no point in modifying cmdTxt after "new SqlCommand(cmdTxt.ToString(), con);" because the command text has already been set in stone
2. You should be using roleId1, roleId2, etc. You can't re-use the same name. Try cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roleId"+x.ToString(), authGroup[x]);
3. you have a typo: roleIdr vs roleId

Answer (score 1):

Add a line right before you create the command to add in what is needed to the where.  I've shown one way here... if you would rather a loop you could do a loop.  The first line is just for context.

```
cmdTxt.Append(" WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeId AND RoleId = @roleId");
cmdTxt.Append("  AND RoleID IN ('"+authorizedGroup.Replace(";","','")+"')");
```

Comment: @TudorCarean - you are right -- the OP has to figure out what he wants -- I expect `and RoleId = @roleId` is an artifact and should be taken out, but I can't tell from the quesiton

Comment: Why do you suggest turning a parameterized query back into a string-concatenated query?

Comment: @CodeCaster - because there is no easy way to have a list in a parameter except with a table parameter.  But you are right -- it is probably not a good solution even if the string is coming from the config file.  Of course if the config file is compromised your db is the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder cmdTxt = new StringBuilder();
            cmdTxt.Append("SELECT EmployeeID, RoleID, RoleDescription");
            cmdTxt.Append(" FROM vstaffInfo");
            cmdTxt.Append(" WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeId ");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdTxt.ToString(), con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", UserID);

            if (authGroup.Length == 1)
            {
                cmdTxt.Append(" AND RoleId = @roleId");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roleId", authGroup[0]);
            }
            else if (authGroup.Length > 1)
            {
                cmdTxt.Append(" AND ( RoleId = @roleId");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roleId", authGroup[0]);
                for (int x = 1; x < authGroup.Length; x++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roleId" + x, authGroup[x]);
                    cmdTxt.Append(" OR RoleId = @roleId" + x);
                }
                cmdTxt.Append(")");
            }

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rdr.Close();
            con.Close();
```

Command text will look like below

```
SELECT EmployeeID, RoleID, RoleDescription FROM vstaffInfo WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeId AND ( RoleId = @roleId OR RoleId = @roleId1 OR RoleId = @roleId2 OR RoleId = @roleId3)
```